# i've installed Firefox Developer Edition with Ubuntu Make but I don't find the icon

Tags: software-installation, firefox, 20.04

I have installed Firefox Developer Edition with Ubuntu Make but I dont find the icon

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake web firefox-dev
```

I installed in in es-MX and everything seemed to be ok but when the installation finished i did't found the icon. I use Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umake put Firefox Developer into:

- executable → `~/.local/share/umake/bin/firefox-developer`
- desktop-file → `~/.local/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

What follows is the answer I have found via my adaptation of [this source](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-firefox-developer-edition-on-linux).

1. Login to your admin account & download Firefox Dev Ed from its site [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/). Extract it in the same folder by double-clicking and "Extract". Open the outer folder and cut the folder inside ("firefox") so you can paste it directly into Downloads. Delete the tar.gz folder and now empty extracted folder. Then use "Rename" from the right-click menu to rename the folder "firefox" as "firefox-deved". (Look inside this folder and see compiled binaries, config files and libraries. So there is no need to compile this package.)
2. Open the CLI and copy the downloaded FFDE to the .local directory in your user account. Having it in a user account allows the browser to update itself without root privileges.

   ```
     $ sudo cp -r Downloads/firefox-deved  /home/<user-account>/.local/firefox-deved
   ```
3. Create a soft link between the application launcher and the extracted folder. The launcher file will be a shortcut in the /usr/local/bin folder:

   ```
     $ sudo ln -s  /home/<user-account>/.local/firefox-deved/firefox  /usr/local/bin/firefox-deved
   ```
4. To check operability, open the FFDE application from the CLI via:

   ```
     $ firefox-deved
   ```

The application should open in a few seconds. (There is no need to add /usr/local/bin to the PATH env variable as it's already there !) If it does not open, check your actions against the previous steps.

5. An application launch icon must be added to the appropriate location so that we can see the FFDE blue fox icon on our "Show Applications" menu. To do this we create a file called firefox-deved.application within the folder /home//.local/share/applications:

   ```
     $ cd /home/<user-account>/.local/share/applications

     /home/<user-account>/.local/share/applications $ sudo touch firefox-deved.desktop
   ```

and then edit this empty file via:

```
     /home/<user-account>/.local/share/applications $ sudo gedit firefox-deved.desktop
```

and add the following to the file before saving it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=/usr/local/bin/firefox-deved/firefox %u
Icon=/home/<user-account>/.local/share/applications/firefox-deved/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Keywords=web;browser;internet;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/usr/local/bin/firefox-deved/firefox %u

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=/usr/local/bin/firefox-deved/firefox --private-window %u
```

6. Now have a quick check on the "Show Applications" grid of your admin desktop to see if the blue fox icon for Firefox Developer Edition has been added to it.
7. Restart the PC, login to your user account, check for the FFDE on "Show Applications" and open the new FFDE browser.

NOTE that this manual installation will alert you to updates (unless you configured FFDE to NOT alert you) but it will not carry out updating for you. This has to be done manually, i.e. download and extract the new FFDE update folder, remove the outer folder, rename the inner folder as "firefox-deved" and replace the existing firefox-deved in /opt with this new one.

To ensure the soft-link to the startup executable in /usr/local/bin works, remove the old firefox-deved file and recreate a new soft-link between /opt/firefox-deved/firefox and /usr/local/bin/firefox-deved.